Why does running a script using "Run file" button brings out nothing, while using "Run current cell" button does the job?
When I tried to execute the following script in Spyder3,using the "Run file" button nothing came out.But when I pressed the "Run current cell" button,the script was executed nice and easy.
product = 1
for count in range(4):
    product = product * (count + 1)
product

Using "Run file" button, the outcome is:
runfile('F:/Toshiba (j)/New Volume D/Python/factorial2.py', wdir='F:/Toshiba (j)/New Volume D/Python')

While using "Run current cell" button, the outcome is:
product = 1
for count in range(4):
    product = product * (count + 1)

product
Out[4]: 24

which is right.

The line product does nothing (other than verifying that such a variable actually exists) in a script - but displays the variable's value in interactive mode.  To display the value in a script, you'd need to write print(product) instead.

Thank you very much for the clarification, and thank you for your time and care.
